# C complexed function declaration

Tags: c

I wonder what the following declarations mean in C.

1. `double *(*(*b())[2])[3] ;`
2. `float *(*c(char))(int *)`

I think b is something like pointer to array....but I can't understand the structure of the function

please give me some hint to figure it out

Comment: Take a look at https://cdecl.org/

Comment: Also helpful: [http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html]